# Win10 Boot Time/Duration via Event Viewer

Tags: windows-10, boot, c#

I am trying to get the "Boot Duration" of a win10 machine. I have tried to serach it in the registry and did not find it. I searched a lot in the internet but did not find a solution. The only time I was able to get a Start Duration was the Event Viewer under the Diagnostics-Performance Folder. Unfortunately the Event Viewer only provides the Boot Duration if there is a Warning or an Error. Is there a way to force the Event Viewer to generate LogFiles each start? Or is there another way of getting the Boot Duration?

Background: I am writing a c# application where I could need this value.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found on [Microsoft's forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/48005f5d-5f66-439a-af51-3a2ebb894e31/diagnosticsperformance-log-event-100-critical-error-or-warning-when-and-why?forum=w7itproperf)

It looks like any boot time under 30 seconds is labeled as a `Warning`.

> For example, a PostBootTime of 0 to 30 seconds will get a level of Warning, 30-60 seconds gets Error, and greater than 60 gets Critical.

[Another source](https://malwaretips.com/threads/find-your-boot-time-in-windows-8-10.50270/) mentions that you can also see how long it takes to get from BIOS to the Welcome screen through `Task Manager > Startup`, which is pretty neat.